# How do we set the horizontal value component of a selected direction of border-radius directly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-applications

[MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/border-radius):

> A `border-radius` has 2 values per direction, one is the horizontal
>   value and one is the vertical value.

How do I set the horizontal value of a selected direction (let's assume selected direction is `border-top-left-radius`) without affecting the vertical value and vice-versa?

To be clear, assuming this is the start state:

```
border-top-left-radius:     1em 2em;
border-top-right-radius:    3em 4em;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5em 6em;
border-bottom-left-radius:  7em 8em;
```

How do I get to the end state:

```
border-top-left-radius:     100em 2em;
border-top-right-radius:    3em 4em;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5em 6em;
border-bottom-left-radius:  7em 8em;
```

I couldnt' simply `style.borderTopLeftRadius="100em 2em";` since I do not know beforehand that the vertical component is 2em.

One way I've thought of is to read the  current border-top-left-radius using `style.borderTopLeftRadius` and do some string parsing to determine if the vertical value is set and if it is, extract that value.

Well of course I'm looking for a better solution than having to try to analyze the string. basically I'm looking for something like: `style.borderTopLeftRadiusHorizontal="100em";`

Answer (score 0):

Haven't you just answered your own question? To set a border radius of `100em` you set the value to `100em`. I'm confused as to what you're trying to ask.

```
border-top-left-radius:     1em 2em;
border-top-right-radius:    3em 4em;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5em 6em;
border-bottom-left-radius:  7em 8em;
```

In this code block, the two values correspond to the horizontal and vertical radii, respectively. In this example, the top left corner will have a horizontal radius of 1em, and a vertical radius of 2em. Changing either value has no effect on the other value.

```
border-top-left-radius:     10em 2em;
```

This would still have a vertical radius of 2em.

I noticed in your original example you used 100em as a value - you'd need to make sure the element you're applying this to  is large enough for 100em to be noticeable and worthwhile.

Comment: 100 is merely an arbitrary value used to ensure the question is conveyed clearly. take a look at the question again

Comment: I'll take a look now you've edited it.

I'm sorry that I can't help further but I honestly don't understand what it is you're asking.

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the value dynamically using Javascript, having no knowledge of the value?